# Duo boot win7 and Ubuntu error

Tags: windows-7, easybcd

When I boot up I can access windows 7 easily and it works fine at the moment but when I select to boot Ubuntu this error appears https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNrJ.jpg when I press esc Ubuntu boots but that error is a bit weird isn't it? There's obviously an error, can someone explain why it's happening and how to fix it? I used EasyBCD to create the boot menu thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10, but I got the same error message when I was trying to install Ubuntu. The error occurs because your computer has Windows set as the default OS, so every time you boot your computer it tries to go into Windows no matter what.

It might be a little different for you, but I had to turn off fast boot, make Windows no longer my default OS, and then change the boot order. The first change was somewhere in the control panel, in the System Settings I believe. The latter two changes had to be done from the BIOS menu (which I access by pushing the DEL key when my computer starts up, but apparently this is different for all computers. As an alternative, you can hold down the SHIFT key when you click Restart and there you should find some option to change the UEFI preferences or boot into BIOS.)